# Sonar coding rule modify

Tags: coding-style, sonarqube

I have an issue.

I need to modify java "**if/else/for/while/do statements should always use curly braces**" coding rule into sonar Quality Profiles.

**if/else/for/while/do statements should always use curly braces** Not
 using curly braces could be error-prone in some cases. For instance in
 the following example, the two statements seems to be attached to the
if statement whereas this is the case only for the first one:

```
if (condition) // Non-Compliant   
executeSomething();   
checkSomething();

if (condition) { // Compliant   
executeSomething(); 
}
checkSomething();
```

I need to extend it with adding one exclusion.

I should to keep this rule but add exception:

> if (Logging.ENABLED) Logging.*

this expression should be ignored by this rule. Its mean that alarm should not appear when i write e.g.

> if (Logging.ENABLED) Logging.logThrowable(LOG_TAG, e);

Could you be so kind how exactly step by step i can do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set an exclusion. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus#NarrowingtheFocus-IgnoreIssues ("Ignore Issues in Blocks" section). Start block can be "Logging.ENABLED" and End block can be "$". The only drawback for now is that it'll ignore all issues on this line. Feel free to vote for http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5122 if it's not ok with you.